# How do I solve first order non-linear system of PDE: $\partial f^i(x,y)/\partial z = F^i(f^1,f^2,...,f^n)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose that I have a system of PDEs of the following form:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial f^i(x,y)}{\partial z} = F^i(f^1,f^2,...,f^n), \qquad i = 1,..,n
\end{eqnarray}
Where $z = x + iy$, $\partial/\partial z = (1/2)(\partial/\partial x - i\partial/\partial y)$ and $F$ is a known complex-valued non-linear expressions involving $n$ unknown functions $f^i$. None of $f^i$ are assumed to be analytic, so $f^i = f^i(z,z^*)$. I've got a lot of PDE systems of this form to solve for my research, but I'm probably the furthest person from being an expert in PDE. Just to make the question more concrete, one of my system looks like:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} &= \lambda_1(v^n - \phi^{*n}) - \lambda_2n\phi^{*n-1}\chi^* \\
\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial z} &= \lambda_2(v^n - \phi^{*n} - \chi^{*n})
\end{align}
Where $\lambda_{1,2}, n$ and $v$ are known constants. But I also have many more of these. So it would be great if someone could help me (or point me out to right reading resources) solve this analytically or numerically (i.e. numerical method that can be implement nicely in Mathematica but I don't mind other software such as MATLAB).

Comment: Wait, when you say that $F,G, $ and $H$ are unknown, do you just mean they are arbitrary? Don't they have to be fixed and known when you try to solve it?

Comment: yes that's a bit misleading sorry. I know the expression for the particular problem I'm dealing with but I'm just asking in general as well. Will fix the question now.